# How to change local Service Fabric default launch url?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I created a stateless service in service fabric local cluster with Visual studio 2017.
It came with a predefined random port 8462.

I changed the port in the ServiceManifest.xml to another, but every time I launch the project it goes to the old port, I can see in the Output "**Launching the browser with URL http://localhost:8462/ to open the application.**" and I have to change it manually.

Ho I change the default launch url? in the project properties there is no option.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right click the Service Fabric Application project (so, not the project of a service) and select "properties". You can modify it there:

[image: Setting launch url]