# How to View UI of service fabric application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Service Fabric. please let me know if there is any way to browse the application which I have hosted in a service fabric cluster. I am unable to see any option to browse the application in service fabric explorer.

Comment: What kind of application did you deploy? If it is a web app you have to manually browse to the specified url. Maybe this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277667/how-to-change-local-service-fabric-default-launch-url/43279979#43279979?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "browse the application"? I suggest that you try this step by step demo, if you are new to this, it will give you an overview on what's going on. you will have a link to see your app homepage.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1217885/Azure-Service-Fabric-demo