# Service Fabric: Waiting for URL http://localhost:9027/api/values to be ready

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, azure-service-fabric

When attempting to debug an SF application locally, Visual Studio's output window eventuates in showing this message over and over again:

```
Waiting for URL http://localhost:9027/api/values to be ready...
```

Where does it get this URL from? I searched for "values" through all files in my project and found it only in `launchSettings.json` and a comment in a deployment script. Even after modifying `launchSettings.json`, VS *still* waits for this URL to become available when debugging.

It got to the point where I added a dummy values controller back into my project just to get the debugger to start!

Comment: You can set it using VS, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277667/how-to-change-local-service-fabric-default-launch-url/43279979#43279979)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it in `$PROJECT_NAME.sfproj.user`. I have no idea why but it didn't show up in VS Code find-in-files results until I opened the file in VS Code :/

Comment: So you were using Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio? Also, I am wondering what you did.